# Are derivative and the slope same?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have a doubt. Please correct me if I’m mistaken. Derivative is considered as rate of change = slope isn’t it?

If the derivative of $x^2$ is $2x$, that means slope = $2x$.

But $f(2)=4$, so the slope should be ${4\over 2}=2$; but here $2x=4$.

Please help me regarding this.

---

*Original text*:

Please help me regarding this doubt.
I've just started my derivative lessons

Please find this image :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/egEvQ.jpg

Thanks

Comment: You should always make the question self-contained. I've edited in the text of your linked question, with minor edits. In the future, though, do this yourself.

Comment: Please post what is written on your paper. In this format it is unreadable.

Comment: Slope at a point on a curve isn't defined as $\frac{f(x)}{x}$.  It's no even defined as $\frac{f(x_1)-f(x_2)}{x_1-x_2}$ unless the curve is a line.  So no slope shouldn't be $\frac 42$.

Comment: Two answers up to now without knowing the intention of the OP.

Comment: @callculus The original image is mostly readable and there are only a couple of hangups that OP could have given what's written.

Comment: @BobbieD I don´t think so. I think he is also confused that the slope is not constant, But I dont know. I really like to interpretate questions but in my view it is impossible to give an appropiate question here. We will see.

Comment: @callculus Well, assuming OP isn't going to clarify, there are only two choices: we either close this question or attempt to answer it.  Only one of those options is useful for future readers.  But I'd respect anyone's choice either way.

Comment: @BobbieD Waiting a few minutes and then voting for close is the choice I would prefer. The most  question are closed for less important reasons.

Answer (score 4):

Rather you should think of it as a **function that can give you a slope**.

For example, in your case of
$$x^2$$

The **derivative is** $2x$.

What that means is that at **any x-coordinate of** $x^2$, you can get the **slope**, by plugging in that x coordinate, into your **derivative**.

It's like slope, but not the exact same.

Rather it's a **function** that **gives** you slope.

Consider $$\sin(x)$$

It's derivative is $\cos(x)$. $\cos(x)$ is not a slope. That doesn't make sense. Rather its a **function** that can give you a slope of the **original** function. So if we wanted the slope at $x=0$ of $\sin(x)$, we plug in $x=0$ into it's **derivative** and we see the slope is $\cos(0)=1$. Remember, slope is a **number**, not a **function.**

Answer (score 2):

You write that the slope of $f(x)=x^2$ at $x=2$ is ${f(2)\over 2}$. This is incorrect; the value of ${f(x)\over x}$ has nothing to do with the slope.

Here's a concrete way to see that $f(x)\over x$ can't have anything to do with the slope. Consider the function $g(x)=x^2+100$. If you draw this, it's clear that it is "parallel" to $f(x)=x^2$. So the slope of $g$ at $x=2$ should be the same as the slope of $f$ at $x=2$. But $g(2)\over 2$
 is $52$, whereas $f(2)\over 2$ is $2$. So these numbers can't be the slopes!

---

I think you're misremembering the usual *rise-over-run* definition of the slope of a line: the slope of the line through $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ is $${y_2-y_1\over x_2-x_1}.$$ But note that this is very different from e.g. ${y_2\over x_2}$ - it takes into account *two* points!

---

EDIT: Bobbie's comment below suggests that you might be looking at the line from $(0, 0^2)$ to $(2, 2^2)$. This line indeed has slope $2$; however, *it's not the tangent line*! If you draw it, you'll notice that - where it meets the parabola - the parabola is much steeper (= has greater slope). So - if this is what you're doing - you have measured the slope of *a* line, just not the *right* line.

Comment: OP might be using $(0,0^2)$ as the other point.

Comment: @BobbieD Thanks, that's a good point - I've incorporated it.

Comment: I'm curious, why the downvote?

Comment: I'm curious about that, too. I upvoted both answers, but I actually think yours is better.